# How to count every entries for each day in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a query that formats bigint values into dates like this "01-01-1970".

My results look like this :

```
date    
28-01-2021
14-07-2021
15-08-2021
14-07-2021
....
```

I have duplicate dates in my result, and what I need is to get something like this (and ordered by date descending):

```
   count    date    
    1        28-01-2021
    2        14-07-2021
    1        15-08-2021
    ....
```

I tried this :

```
  SELECT count(to_char(to_timestamp(last_downloaded/1000),
  'DD-MM-YYYY')), to_char(to_timestamp(last_downloaded/1000) from stats;
```

But it does not give me what I want..

Comment: Use proper **date** data type!

Comment: @jarlh, which means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `group by`. However as @jarlh noted you have to first convert the strings to `date` or - better - store data as the native type and not as formatted text..

```sql
with t(d) as
(
 values
 ('28-01-2021'),
 ('14-07-2021'),
 ('15-08-2021'),
 ('14-07-2021')
)
select to_date(d, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), count(1)
from t
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

In case your bigint values are epoch timestamps in milliseconds then

```sql
with t(dts) as
(
 values
 (1632837719969),
 (1632837719969),
 (1632700800123),
 (1632614400234),
 (1630330448696)
)
select to_timestamp(dts/1000)::date, count(1)
from t
group by 1 order by 1 desc;
```

Result:

| to_timestamp | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-28 | 2 |
| 2021-09-27 | 1 |
| 2021-09-26 | 1 |
| 2021-08-30 | 1 |

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not work for me. I tried : select to_date(last_downloaded, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), count(1) from stats group by 1 order by 1 desc;, but I get this error ERROR:  function to_date(bigint, unknown) does not exist HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Comment: because your `last_downloaded` is already a date type, I assume. @Stefanov.sm example assume it's a string, hence he use `to_date` to convert it.

Comment: Is this bigint value an epoch timestamp in milliseconds? Can you provide examples?

Comment: The bigint values look like this : 1630330448696

Comment: Fine, this _is_ an epoch timestamp in ms, 2021-08-30 13:34:08.000Z. See updated answer.